# Can we create PostgreSQL table-space to point to different Drive outside of data folder

Tags: postgresql

Can we create PostgreSQL table-space to point to different  Drive outside of **C** Dirve
Actually my PostgreSQL data drive is **C** I can create folders inside it for different namespaces but I want to be able to create namespace pointing to drive **D**

Comment: Yes you can. table-space exactly for this.

Comment: how I can. do postgresql allow to move outside of data folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this is how I managed to create table space
and then at time when you create table then you can assign the tablespace what you want.

in location you can give location of your drive **D:\gg**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You should create tablespaces *only* outside the data directory.

It makes no sense to create a tablespace on the same device as the data directory.

On Windows, you should be able to

```
CREATE TABLESPACE tbsp LOCATION 'D:\tbsp';
```